# Go httputil.ReverseProxy not overriding the Host header

Tags: go

I'm basically trying to write a reverse proxy server so that when I `curl localhost:8080/get` it proxies the request to `https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/get`.

> Note: the https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/get service listed above is http/2. But this behavior happens with http/1 as well, such as https://httpbin.org/get.

I'm using [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) for this and I'm rewriting the URL while customizing the `Host` header to not to leak the `localhost:8080` to the actual backend.

However, the request still hits the backend with `Host: localhost:8080` no matter how many times I set it on the header. Similarly, I used `mitmproxy` to snoop on the request and it looks like the net/http.Client sets the `:authority` pseudo-header to `localhost:8080`

Here's my source code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func main() {
    proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{
        Transport: roundTripper(rt),
        Director: func(req *http.Request) {
            req.URL.Scheme = "https"
            req.URL.Host = "nghttp2.org"
            req.URL.Path = "/httpbin" + req.URL.Path
            req.Header.Set("Host", "nghttp2.org") // <--- I set it here first
        },
    }
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy))
}

func rt(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    log.Printf("request received. url=%s", req.URL)
    req.Header.Set("Host", "nghttp2.org") // <--- I set it here as well
    defer log.Printf("request complete. url=%s", req.URL)

    return http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
}


// roundTripper makes func signature a http.RoundTripper
type roundTripper func(*http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
func (f roundTripper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) { return f(req) }
```

When I query `curl localhost:8080/get` the request gets proxied to https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/get. The echoed response shows that clearly my directives setting the `Host` header didn't do anything:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Host": "localhost:8080",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"
  },
  "origin": "2601:602:9c02:16c2:fca3:aaab:3914:4a71",
  "url": "https://localhost:8080/httpbin/get"
}
```

mitmproxy snooping also clearly shows that the request was made with `:authority` pseudo-header set to `localhost:8080`:
[image: mitmproxy output shows :authority pseudoheader set to localhost:8080]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `http.Request` [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request):

> ```
>         // For server requests, Host specifies the host on which the URL
>         // is sought. Per RFC 7230, section 5.4, this is either the value
>         // of the "Host" header or the host name given in the URL itself.
>         // It may be of the form "host:port". For international domain
>         // names, Host may be in Punycode or Unicode form. Use
>         // golang.org/x/net/idna to convert it to either format if
>         // needed.
>         // To prevent DNS rebinding attacks, server Handlers should
>         // validate that the Host header has a value for which the
>         // Handler considers itself authoritative. The included
>         // ServeMux supports patterns registered to particular host
>         // names and thus protects its registered Handlers.
>         //
>         // For client requests, Host optionally overrides the Host
>         // header to send. If empty, the Request.Write method uses
>         // the value of URL.Host. Host may contain an international
>         // domain name.
>         Host string
> ```

So the value of `URL.Host` is only used in case `request.Host` is empty which is not the case. Setting `request.Host` should resolve the issue:

```
req.Host = "nghttp2.org"
```

Related issue discussed [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7682).